# User is logged in but who command doesn't list that user as logged in, how to resolve this issue?

Tags: login, write

I'm on centos 7 minimal.

I've duplicated a SSH session at 192.168.169.128 in 2 tabs of mobaxterm.

In first tab, I've logged in as "server1" user. Whereas in second tab, I've logged in as root.

I want to send a message from root to "server1". Expected output is server1 should see that message.

But that's not happening.

The command I am using on root to write a message to server1 is:

`write server1`

The error that I'm getting is:

write: server1 is not logged in

It only works when I do

`write root`.

Why is it not detecting server1 as logged in user? How do I fix this issue?

PS: The who command doesn't show server1 as logged user although I've logged into it (server1 doesn't have password)

```
root     tty1         2023-05-04 11:45
root     pts/0        2023-05-04 11:45 (192.168.169.1)
root     pts/1        2023-05-04 11:46 (192.168.169.1)
```

Comment: How do you log as "server1", give please the command you use

Comment: `su - server1` and press enter.

Comment: To have user visible login like: `ssh server1@192.168.169.128`